# no persistent volumes available for this claim on kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, efk

I'm trying to set up elasticsearch on kubernetes with Helm(**helm install elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch -n efk**). I get the error "no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set". how can i solve

**Log**

```
LAST SEEN           TYPE      REASON               OBJECT                                                              MESSAGE
18s (x2 over 18s)   Normal    NoPods               PodDisruptionBudget/elasticsearch-master-pdb                        No matching pods found
18s                 Normal    SuccessfulCreate     StatefulSet/elasticsearch-master                                    create Claim elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-2 Pod elasticsearch-master-2 in StatefulSet elasticsearch-master success
18s                 Normal    SuccessfulCreate     StatefulSet/elasticsearch-master                                    create Pod elasticsearch-master-1 in StatefulSet elasticsearch-master successful
18s                 Normal    SuccessfulCreate     StatefulSet/elasticsearch-master                                    create Claim elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-1 Pod elasticsearch-master-1 in StatefulSet elasticsearch-master success
18s                 Normal    SuccessfulCreate     StatefulSet/elasticsearch-master                                    create Pod elasticsearch-master-0 in StatefulSet elasticsearch-master successful
18s                 Normal    SuccessfulCreate     StatefulSet/elasticsearch-master                                    create Claim elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0 Pod elasticsearch-master-0 in StatefulSet elasticsearch-master success
18s                 Normal    SuccessfulCreate     StatefulSet/elasticsearch-master                                    create Pod elasticsearch-master-2 in StatefulSet elasticsearch-master successful
18s                 Warning   FailedScheduling     Pod/elasticsearch-master-0                                          0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
18s                 Warning   FailedScheduling     Pod/elasticsearch-master-1                                          0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
18s                 Warning   FailedScheduling     Pod/elasticsearch-master-2                                          0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
16s                 Warning   FailedScheduling     Pod/elasticsearch-master-0                                          0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
16s                 Warning   FailedScheduling     Pod/elasticsearch-master-1                                          0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
8s (x2 over 18s)    Normal    FailedBinding        PersistentVolumeClaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0   no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
8s (x2 over 18s)    Normal    FailedBinding        PersistentVolumeClaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-2   no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
8s (x2 over 18s)    Normal    FailedBinding        PersistentVolumeClaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-1   no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do achieve this, first you have to create `StorageClass`, you can refer to this documentation on how you can [set your storage class in yaml manifest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-volume-claim-templates.html#k8s-volume-claim-templates).
 
You can use as reference this yaml from [willes](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/eck-pvc-pending/229919/7)

```html
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.6.2
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 3
    config:
      node.master: true
      node.data: true
      node.ingest: true
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
        storageClassName: standard
```